# How to store all usernames in lowercase?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

```
username = db.StringProperty(required = True)
```

^How do I store the username in lowercase, using GAE.

Comment: First convert it to lower case, then store it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my_string.lower()` converts a python string to all lowercase